# Angular/JAWS, Stop JAWS from re-reading a form after submit

Tags: angularjs, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

I have a problem in Internet Explorer 9.  I have a form that searches for a person by name.  When I land on the page, JAWS reads all the fields correctly.  I enter my input, I hit the submit button, JAWS re-reads all the fields again while the system performs a search.  I want to prevent this from happening.  So I figured, let me add an ID in my div and prevent this from happening in my controller.

In my HTML I added:
div id="JawsId" ng-controller="SomeController as someController"

in someController I added the following to my search function:
angular.element('#jawsId').attr('aria-live', 'off');

This has no impact.  Has anyone encountered this problem and know of a way to prevent JAWS from re-reading a form after hitting the submit button?  Any advice or clues would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This would easier to debug if we could see the rendered page.

I am not surprised `aria-live` does not work. That is intended for dynamically updating content blocks, not what I suspect you are doing.

Instead, try setting its style to `display: none`. If that does not work, you can also try `aria-hidden="true"`.

How does this perform in IE11? In my experience, most JAWS users are on IE11.

Comment: Thanks,  I didn't know that about aria-live.  It's my first go with aria, so much to learn.  I'll try your suggestions!  Unfortunately, our app has to be complaint with IE9.